# do i need filling the missing value of categorical or numeric after merging multiple dataframe?

Tags: rows, numeric, categorical-data, fillna

I have 3 dataframe with different row columns length and I merge it in. for example:

Table A:

[image]

Table B:

[image]

Table C:

[image]

The output after merge:

[image]

the question :
after merging multiple dataframe into one dataframe, there is a NaN because each of columns has different rows columns. do i need to fill in the missing values using mode for categorical values or means and median for numeric values before i do the data visualization?